# Proper Syntax for T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm no SQL expert, but rarely fail to come up with a query that returns the results needed (even if it's sub-optimal). But this one has me stuck.

I have two tables, People and Organizations. People has a FK over to Organizations (a person can have an organization, but the default is NULL). I'm trying to run a search query that will pull up people (with a couple fields from Organizations table), as follows:

```
DECLARE
    @text nvarchar(100)     = 'test',
    @jobTitle nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @orgName nvarchar(100)  = NULL,
    @industry nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @location nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @status nvarchar(100)   = NULL

SELECT
    PeopleId AS 'ID',
    FirstName + ' ' + People.LastName AS 'People',
    Email AS 'Email',
    JobTitle AS 'Job Title',
    Location AS 'Location',
    Organizations.Name AS 'Employer',
    Organizations.Industry AS 'Industry',
    People.Status AS 'Status'
FROM
    People, Organizations
WHERE
    (People.Organization = Organizations.OrganizationId) 
    AND ((FirstName LIKE '%' + @text + '%' OR 
          LastName LIKE '%' + @text + '%' OR 
          Email LIKE '%' + @text + '%' OR
          @text IS NULL) 
    AND (JobTitle LIKE '%' + @jobTitle + '%' 
         OR @jobTitle IS NULL)                  
    AND (Organizations.Name LIKE '%' + @orgName + '%' 
         OR @orgName IS NULL)
    AND (Organizations.Industry LIKE '%' + @industry + '%' 
         OR @industry IS NULL)
    AND (Location LIKE  '%' + @location + '%' 
         OR @location IS NULL)
    AND (People.Status LIKE  '%' + @status + '%' 
         OR @location IS NULL)            
    );
```

This returns the right people (but with a row for every single organization in that table). Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?

I thought I might need to add a `OR People.Organization IS NULL` condition to the first clause under the `WHERE`, but that simply brings back no results at all :(

Kind thanks.

Comment: You are using implicit joins, for starters. Use proper joins.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks! Old habits die hard, although mine wasn't nearly that old. I'll have to dig into this a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left outer join

```
FROM 
    People 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Organizations ON (People.Organization = Organizations.OrganizationId)
```

The problem is that `FROM People, Organizations` creates a so called "cross product" or "cartesian product" of the two tables, which contains all combinations of all People with all Organizations. When the condition `(People.Organization = Organizations.OrganizationId)` take only meaningful combinations from the cross product, it doesn't find People with no Organizations. It doesn't have a chance to find them, because only People paired with some Organization are found in the cross product.

The left outer join is exactly what you need. It takes all the People (this is the meaning of "left outer"), and Organizations as far as it is found. If it doesn't find it, all the fields of the Organization seems to be null, but the People record is still there.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer and vote for all good answers ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You basic problem is that you need a left join which Stefan covered, but I wanted to point out another trick you can use for null parameters defaulting to "ALL"

instead of a construct like this

```
AND (Organizations.Industry LIKE '%' + @industry + '%' 
     OR @industry IS NULL)
```

use the COALESCE function

```
AND (Organizations.Industry LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@industry,Organizations.Industry) + '%'
```

I would also point out that a "wildcard" search like this is very slow (can't use indexes.  If you know your input is exact (eg from a dropdown) this is much better:

```
AND Organizations.Industry = COALESCE(@industry,Organizations.Industry)
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan. Frankly, I've seen discussion of COALESCE online, but haven't really looked into it. As you've prob gathered, I learned SQL a million years ago and haven't really kept up with anything introduced since 1970. Back to school for me :)